# Send File Content in setText (Java Mail)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a *jsp* file:

**email.jsp**

```
<div id="foo">
    <span id="bar">test</span>
</div>
```

Now i want to send the content of **email.jsp** by **setText** method of Java Mail like this:

e.g.:

```
email.setText(getFileContent("email.jsp"));
```

will result in something like:

```
email.setText("<div id="foo"><span id="bar">test</span></div>");
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an utility method :

```
 /**
 * @param fileName String: Path of the JSP file 
 * @return jspContent String : contents of the JSP file
 * @throws IOException
 */
private String readJSPContents(String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream io = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));
    String str;
    String jspContent = "";
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
        jspContent+=str;
    in.close();
    return jspContent;
}
```

Then , `email.setText(readJSPContents("email.jsp"), "utf-8", "html");`